# Mongodb positional operators $ or $[] do not work for array elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

```
{
    "_id": "5aa9535c6c4f437de713452a",
     ...
    "ht_score": "[0-1]",
    "ft_score": "[1-3]",
    "et_score": null,
    "penalty_local": null,
    "penalty_visitor": null,
    "comp_name": "UEFA Champions League",
    "predictions": [
        {
            "name": "Ilker Baltaci",
            "userid": "*******",
            "userFbid": "*****",
            "local_team_score": "3",
            "away_team_score": "1",
            "status": "FT"
        },
        {
            "name": "M. Mustermann",
            "userid": "*******",
            "userFbid": "*****",
            "status": "FT"
        }
    ],
    "match_id": "2324756"
}
```

I have in my mongo db the above collection structure and I want to update some fields of the document as well a field in all objects that reside inside the nested array(predictions).

The reason for the bulk operation is that this code is run as migration over multiple documents.

The problem is that everthing inside `$set` till                                 `"predictions.$[].status" : "FT"` works fine but somehow the positional operator $[] does not seem to work.If i replace it with an number index it updates the corresponding object inside the array.I want to update all nested documents inside the  array.
I tried both $[] and $ to access status but no luck.

```
var bulk = db.collection('bets').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            predictions.forEach(function (currentPrediction) {
                //Find one and update
                let match = games[currentPrediction.match_id];
                const query = {'_id': new ObjectID(currentPrediction._id)};
                bulk.find(query).update(
                    {
                        $set: {
                            status: match.status,
                            timer: match.timer,
                            localteam_score: match.localteam_score,
                            visitorteam_score: match.visitorteam_score,
                            ht_score: match.ht_score,
                            ft_score: match.ft_score,
                            et_score: match.et_score,
                            penalty_local: match.penalty_local,
                            penalty_visitor: match.penalty_visitor,
                            "predictions.$[].status" : "FT"
                        }
                    },{ multi: true });
            })

            bulk.execute(function (err) {
                resolve(predictions)
            });
        }
        catch
            (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** I get the following error

```
       "errmsg": "cannot use the part (predictions of predictions.$[].status) to traverse the element ({predictions: [ { name: \"Ilker Baltaci\", userid: \"***\", userFbid: \"*****\", local_team_score: \"3\", away_team_score: \"0\", status: \"FT22\" }, { name: \"M. Mustermann\", userid: \"***\", userFbid: \"****\", status: \"FT\" } ]})",
```

Comment: *does not seem to work* is not quite a problem statement. Assuming the error you get reads something like "cannot traverse an element", you need to set [compatibility version](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) to `3.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all) is a new feature of v3.6.

For it to work you need mongodb v3.6, **and** set [FeatureCompatibilityVersion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) to "3.6".

---

[$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) updates a single element in the array.

For it to work your query should include a filter for elements in the array, e.g.

```
const query = {'_id': new ObjectID(currentPrediction._id), "predictions.status" : "FT"};
```

The `$` refers to the **first matching** element, and without filter there are no matches.

Comment: thank you, alex. Unfortunately i can't update my version to 3.6 and have to stickwith 3,4 for a while. Is there any other ways to achive to update all array elements expect $[]?

Comment: No. In v3.4 you need either to update 1 subdocument at a time, or to do it  clientside and replace whole array.